# G Suite and Amazon SES MX records

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ses, mx-record, google-workspace

I need to store all received emails from a certain email address into AWS S3 buckets.

I'm using G Suite for emails using a domain name.

Is it possible to have 2 MX records so the emails I receive can be stored in S3 while having the rest of the email addresses work as normal?

Answer (score 1):

No you cannot have 2 MX Records. Possible solution I can think of is that let email be sent to Gmail; and using simple Gmail apis ( through which u can even configure that emails ONLY from a particular email account ) send  that email back to AWS..

Using Gmail APIs you can even call an API endpoint exposed by AWS which would save the email into S3.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using GMAIL you can create an aliases-subdomain, take a look at my answer over here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/62452983/5285732